# Iterating through an array of specific properties using getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, arrays, getcomputedstyle

Sorry for the stupid 101 question. I'm not sure why this is not working. I'm trying to iterate through the various margin properties that are returned using getComputedStyle()

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance - CES

```
   const constContentContainerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(constHTMLContentContainer);

let tmpStylesArray = ["marginTop", "marginLeft", "marginBottom", "marginRight"];
let x = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < tmpStylesArray.length; i++) {

    //This throws undefined error
    // x = constContentContainerStyles.tmpStylesArray[i];

    //This returns 0
    x = constContentContainerStyles.getPropertyValue(tmpStylesArray[i]);
    console.log(tmpStylesArray[i] + " - " + x);
    
    // returns the correct value
    console.log(constContentContainerStyles.marginTop);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) expects hyphen-case names (`"margin-top"`, etc., not `"marginTop"`, etc.).

But you can just use the style object directly via brackets notation:

```
console.log(constContentContainerStyles[tmpStylesArray[i]]);
```

That supports camelCase (`"marginTop"`) and hyphen-case (`"margin-top"`):

```js
const constHTMLContentContainer = document.getElementById("target");

const constContentContainerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(constHTMLContentContainer);

const tmpStylesArray = [
    "marginTop",
    "margin-top", // Added this to show it works too
    "marginLeft",
    "marginBottom",
    "marginRight"
];

for (const name of tmpStylesArray) {
    const x = constContentContainerStyles[name];
    const note = name.includes("-") ? "Hyphen case works too: " : "";
    console.log(`${note}${name} = ${x}`);
}
```

```css
#target {
    margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">x</div>
```

Comment: NP. I'd normally tell you about things like typos but I'm being lazy today and just figured it would be quicker to fix. But now I've spent time on this comment so who's really the winner :)

Comment: @Andy - :-) Direct corrections like that are always welcome.